# SASS select class that was chained to parent

Tags: sass

I have the following HTML `<div class="parent green"></div>`

The `green` class may or may not be added. It is dynamic. It may also be another name.

In SASS how do I give properties to a `.child` element of `parent` when class `green` is chained to it?

I tried:

```
.parent {
   .child {
      .green & {
        color: green;
      }
   }
}
```

It doesn't work.

I also tried the following which works but I am looking for something similar to the sass above. The code will become repeatable  below because I have to add `child` each time for every dynamic class.

```
  .parent {
     &.green {
       .child {        
          color: green;
       }
     }
   }
```

I'm trying to get a structure like this if possible with sass:

```
.parent {
       .child {
          .green & { /* when .parent.green */
            color: green;
          }
          .blue & { /* when .parent.blue */
            color: blue;
          }
          .text-align-right & { /* when .parent.text-align-right */
            text-align: right;
          }
          etc...
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is treated as [parent selector reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) in Sass, because of this your code doesn't work since it refers wrong selector.

Use of `&` directly will not help here, but your goal can be achieved by using mixins, for example:

```
@mixin child($class) {
  &.#{$class} {
    .child {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

.parent {
  @include child(green) {
    color: green;
  }
  @include child(blue) {
    color: blue;
  }
  @include child(text-align-right) {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

This piece of code produces result that you want to get, you can check in by yourself on [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/26c872a48c3caf6e240240856a3191f0).